# Can't give input in Command Prompt

Tags: command-prompt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GV9iW.jpg)[i can't give the second input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLvoJ.jpg)

Whenever i try to open a directory using command prompt on windows 10(64 bit),a white pop shows up(as shown in the image) and after that i can't enter second command (i can't type anything).

Answer (score 0):

That is cmd's command history popup.

You open it by pressing F7, and close it by pressing Esc.

If it opens on its own, your F7 key may be stuck or broken.